# on prepositional collocations with ,,beschäftigt sein'' in the sense of 'be busy in doing sth.'

Tags: difference, usage, preposition

The most likely collocation pattern is *mit etw. beschäftigt sein.*

However, the following example is found in Duden:

*sie waren **um** den Verunglückten beschäftigt*

I am wondering how to justify the option for **um** instead of *mit* in this case.

Comment: Could you please fix your quotation marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **(a)** sie waren **mit** dem Verunglückten beschäftigt
>
> **(b)** sie waren **um** den Verunglückten beschäftigt

(a) usually means the injured person is touched by helpers, e. g. they apply a dressing.

(b) can also mean physical treatment (if patient is reachable), but always other actions are going on like ordering and using a machine to cut them off the car or a bulldozer to ensure access.